# Microsft Dynamics SL SoHeader And SalesPerson relationship- Not able to link

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-sl

I am trying to create SalesOrder via api and inserting them into SQL database . Tables I am using :
SOHeader and SOLine

Column to insert into both object : SlsperID
I am able to link line wih SLsperId but not with Soheader. I tried to create it manually and then cloned that row in SQL but still its not linking with Sales order. Maybe there is another table which holds relationship between Salesperson and SOheader

Comment: SQL database? As in MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh - MS SQL Server

Comment: although this is specifically for dynamics sl

Comment: But does it have anything to do with the <sql> _language_? I see no SQL above, do you expected an SQL answer?

Comment: No, I think I am updating table with correct info. Maybe I am missing a table here which does the relationship between these. So I will wait for dynamics-sl ans here

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old... but just in case this is still an issue.... Could you provide some more details about how you are trying to interface with the Dynamics SL database?  You mention that you are "create SalesOrder ***via api*** "... What "API are you using?  There is no API included in the Dynamics SL product, so to answer your question, it would be very helpful to have a better understanding of what interface you are using.